# How do I process multi-character Unicode emojis in Python 3 with the unicodedata module?

Tags: python, unicode, emoji, unicode-normalization

While I was working with emojis and attempting to acquire their codepoint and names with the `unicodedata` module, I kept having issues with multi-character emojis. The module refuses to let me use strings and instead wanted characters. I tried normalizing, I tried encoding in `utf-8` and `unicode-escape`, and I researched it again and again, but I was not successful in finding what was going on!

```py
emojis = ["", "", "", "", "❣️", "✨"]
for emoji in emojis:
    codepoint: str = hex(ord(emoji))
    filename = 'emoji_u{0}.png'.format(codepoint[2:])
    print('{emoji} ({codepoint}) => {filename}'.format(emoji=emoji,
                                                       codepoint=codepoint,
                                                       filename=filename))
```

While yes, the above code does not use the `unicodedata` module, it shows you what I was having a problem with regardless...

```
 (0x1f496) => emoji_u1f496.png
 (0x1f498) => emoji_u1f498.png
 (0x1f49d) => emoji_u1f49d.png
 (0x1f49e) => emoji_u1f49e.png
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Programming/Languages/Vue.js/lovely/collect.py", line 8, in <module>
    codepoint: str = hex(ord(emoji))
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 2 found
```

After a break, somehow, I managed to convert the emoji unintentionally, from this: `❣️` to this: `❣`. Python was able to process this new emoji character perfectly fine. The `unicodedata` module likes it too!

So what's the difference? Why does one have color and not the other in both my browser and IDE? And most importantly, how do I convert multi-character emojis to single-character emojis in Python?

Comment: Multi-code point emojis (called *graphemes*) are obviously made up of multiple code points but represent a single human-perceived character. You have to iterate over the individual points of a grapheme to see how they are constructed

Comment: Emoji can have a text presentation or an emoji presentation. They have a default and variation selectors are used to switch presentation. `❣` is U+2763 and its default presentation is text, so colour of emoji is the colour of the text. `❣️` is U+2763 U+FE0F the same codepoint followed by the variation selector requesting emoji presentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some human-perceived single-character emoji (called *graphemes*) are made up of multiple code points.  Here's a way to handle them.  I added a complicated example:

```py
import unicodedata as ud

emojis = ["", "", "", "", "❣️", "✨", "‍‍‍"]
for emoji in emojis:
    print('Emoji:',emoji)
    for cp in emoji:
        print(f'    {cp} U+{ord(cp):04X} {ud.name(cp)}')
```

Output:

```
Emoji: 
     U+1F496 SPARKLING HEART
Emoji: 
     U+1F498 HEART WITH ARROW
Emoji: 
     U+1F49D HEART WITH RIBBON
Emoji: 
     U+1F49E REVOLVING HEARTS
Emoji: ❣️
    ❣ U+2763 HEAVY HEART EXCLAMATION MARK ORNAMENT
    ️ U+FE0F VARIATION SELECTOR-16
Emoji: ✨
    ✨ U+2728 SPARKLES
Emoji: ‍‍‍
     U+1F468 MAN
    ‍ U+200D ZERO WIDTH JOINER
     U+1F469 WOMAN
    ‍ U+200D ZERO WIDTH JOINER
     U+1F467 GIRL
    ‍ U+200D ZERO WIDTH JOINER
     U+1F466 BOY
```

If the emoji are in a single string the rules for processing a single grapheme are complicated, but implemented by the 3rd party `regex` module.  `\X` matches graphemes:

```py
import unicodedata as ud
import regex

for m in regex.finditer(r'\X', '❣️✨‍‍‍'):
    emoji = m.group(0)
    print(f'{emoji}   {ascii(emoji)}')
```

Output:

```
   '\U0001f496'
   '\U0001f498'
   '\U0001f49d'
   '\U0001f49e'
❣️   '\u2763\ufe0f'
✨   '\u2728'
‍‍‍   '\U0001f468\u200d\U0001f469\u200d\U0001f467\u200d\U0001f466'
```